# Aspect/respect in sentence

Tags: single-word-requests

*"After an hour I reached a different hotel, which was better than the previous one in every aspect/respect."*

I'm struggling with the difference between *aspect* and *respect*. What I wanted to say was something along the line "from every point of view" or "no matter how I looked at it ..."

I have seen *aspect* likened to "point of view" but most other information I have come across online suggests I use *respect*.

Which one is correct, and how can I tell in the future?

Comment: Have you looked up the two words at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/respect etc?

Comment: I can only say I prefer "respect."  "The hotel was better than the previous one in every respect."  I would venture a guess that "respect" would be used by more AE speakers in this application.  "Aspect," on the other hand, would sound better in the following:  "There are many aspects of the issue we have not even considered yet."  Or, "One aspect of good manners is saying 'Thank you.'"  "Aspect," by the way, cannot be used as a verb, as can "respect."

Comment: I would venture a guess that @rhetorician's comments also apply to BrE speakers as well. If someone were talking about the 'aspect' of a hotel, I would understand them as probably discussing the physical position and surroundings of the hotel, and the views from the hotel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I can only say I prefer "respect." "The hotel was better than the previous one in every respect." I would venture a guess that "respect" would be used by more AE speakers in this application. "Aspect," on the other hand, would sound better in the following: "There are many aspects of the issue we have not even considered yet." Or, "One aspect of good manners is saying 'Thank you.'" "Aspect," by the way, cannot be used as a verb, as can "respect."*

– rhetorician

*I would venture a guess that @rhetorician's comments also apply to BrE speakers as well. If someone were talking about the 'aspect' of a hotel, I would understand them as probably discussing the physical position and surroundings of the hotel, and the views from the hotel.*

– TrevorD

Comment: This is a bizarre answer, if that. It looks like two comments by other people to the OP.

Comment: That's exactly what it is. How can I mark a comment as an answer then? Or should I not have marked this question as answered?

Answer (score 2):

Neither is wrong.  In fact, *aspect* is one of the definitions of *respect*. See definition 5 [here](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/respect).

But *aspect* often connotes a visual component, whether actual or virtual. Consider this range of [definitions](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/aspect):

> A particular look or facial expression; mien: "He was serious of aspect but wholly undistinguished" (Louis Auchincloss).
>
> Appearance to the eye, especially from a specific vantage point.
>
> A way in which something can be viewed by the mind: looked at all aspects of the situation. See Synonyms at phase.
>
> A position facing or commanding a given direction; exposure.
>
> A side or surface facing in a particular direction: the ventral aspect of the body.
>
> The configuration of the stars or planets in relation to one another.
>
> This configuration, thought by astrologers to influence human affairs.
>
> Grammar A category of the verb designating primarily the relation of the action to the passage of time, especially in reference to completion, duration, or repetition.
>
> Archaic An act of looking or gazing.

*Respect* connotes a somewhat broader concept of *feature*.

> A particular aspect, feature, or detail: In many respects this is an important decision.

Comment: I'm not happy with 'aspect is one of the definitions of respect'. I'd much prefer 'the words _aspect_ and _respect_ each have a range of meanings, which overlap:  Collins **aspect** (noun) polyseme 2 ( http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aspect ) + the polyseme for 'respect' linked to.